# Redux observable doesn't handle backend response

Tags: javascript, redux, rxjs, redux-observable

I'm implementing an epic for a backend call. The response doesn't get handled as expected.

For my implementation I'm using these modules:

- "axios": "^0.17.1",
- "redux-observable": "^1.1.0",
- "rxjs": "^6.5.2",
- "typesafe-actions": "^4.4.0"

Action.ts

```
export const callBackendAction = createStandardAction('data/GET')();
export const callBackendCompletedAction = createStandardAction('data/LOADED')<IResultDataDTO[]>();
```

Epic.ts

```
export const callBackendEpic: Epic<RootAction, RootAction> = action$ =>
    action$.pipe(
      filter(isActionOf(callBackendAction)),
      switchMap(async () =>
        from(axiosBackendCall())
          .pipe(
            switchMap(({ data }) => {
              return of(callBackendCompletedAction(data.map(data)))
            }),
            catchError(error => of(console.log(error)))
          )
      ),
      catchError(error => of(console.log(error)))
    );
```

Reducer.ts

```
export interface IcallBackendReducerState
{
  data: {}[];
  pending: boolean;
}

const initialState : ICallBackendReducerState =
{
  data: [],
  pending: false
}

export const callBackendReducer = createReducer(initialState)
  .handleAction(callBackendAction, (state: ICallBackendReducerState): ICallBackendReducerState => (
    { ...state, pending: true }
  ))
  .handleAction(callBackendCompletedAction, (state: ICallBackendReducerState, action: PayloadAction<string, any>) => ({
    ...state,
    pending: false,
    data: action.payload
  }));
```

Redux throws an error which could be related to this problem:

`Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.`

My expected output would be a backend call which triggers the reducer to set the pending state to true. <--- this matches the actual output

By receiving the response the reducer should be triggered to update the state with the data and a pending state of false. <--- this doesn't happen

Having a look at the network traffic in my browser shows that the call does complete. The problem is that it's not handled properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem is on these two lines:

```
switchMap(async () =>
  from(axiosBackendCall())
```

By using `async` you make the inner function return a Promise but then you use `from()` that returns an Observable so in fact this arrow function return `Promise<Observable>` which is not what you want. `switchMap` will only subscribe to the Promise and not the nested Observable so `redux` is confused why instead of an action you're passing `Observable`.

So the fix is simple, just don't use `async` because you don't even need it there. `from` will handle the promise returned from `axiosBackendCall()` automatically (I'm assuming `axiosBackendCall` returns a Promise).

```
switchMap(() =>
  from(axiosBackendCall())
    .pipe(...)
),
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It has solved the problem.